[Android 15 ]Update compileSdk Android 35 cause an error : RES_TABLE_TYPE_TYPE entry offsets overlap actual entry data
Updating Android Project to the new version compileSDK Android 35 cause bad behaviour and raise an error :
ERROR:: AAPT: aapt2.exe E 06-27 15:30:04  3616  2980 LoadedArsc.cpp:96] RES_TABLE_TYPE_TYPE entry offsets overlap actual entry data.  
aapt2.exe E 06-27 15:30:04  3616  2980 ApkAssets.cpp:149] Failed to load resources table in APK 'C:\Users\Korisnik\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-35\android.jar'.  
error: failed to load include path 
C:\Users\Korisnik\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-35\android.jar.


This is a very relevant question. I had this same problem and the solution given below unfortunately did not work as the only change. Here's the problem (at least for me) - Google requires that old projects upgrade to newer API versions periodically. After upgrading to API 35 (latest as of today) and bulding, this problem appears. This is due to an incompatibility with the Gradle version it seems. So, I again downgraded to API 34 and then this error dissapeared. But I still use the Gradle versions given in the below solution. My previous comment had an inaccuracy. Therefore, I re-wrote it.

@AsangaUdugama You were on the right track checking the answer below, but I should have specify that  compatible combination matter. Hence downgrading or upgrading is to compatible version combinations should fix it.

To keep using your current gradle plugin version, there is workaround can be done is override maven appt to use aapt 34 or 35 :
android.aapt2FromMavenOverride=<SDK_LOCATION>/build-tools/34.0.0/aapt2.exe

It's an AGP error. Sadly, Google kept the bug in the issue tracker instead of making a blog or a proper error message. Upgrade your project's values as follows (my current working combination):
com.android.tools.build:gradle -> 8.4.2
file:gradle-wrapper.properties : distributionUrl -> gradle-8.6-bin.zip

Check out: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/342522139
Edit: For the future, the above combination might not work so be sure to also check out: https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin#compatibility
The combination matters (so upgrade or downgrade if necessary)

In my case this combination works too (in case you have to stay on Iguana)
com.android.tools.build:gradle -> 8.3.2
file:gradle-wrapper.properties : distributionUrl -> gradle-8.6-bin.zip

Hey -- How exactly do we implement this in Unity (from the top)?  Thanks!
